# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Índice fora dos limites da matriz

Tags: c#

Bom dia! Estou a trabalhar num projeto para a minha PAP, e para uma empresa e não consigo entender que erro é este, já pesquisei em vários locais mas continuo sem entender, preciso de resolver este erro o mais rápido possivel! O meu programa está a passar todos os dados do arduino lidos pelo sensor, para a consola c#, as vezes o programa funciona normalmente outras vezes da erro... Vou colocar o código que me dá erro:

```
 internal static class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var myPort = new SerialPort {BaudRate = 9600, PortName = "COM4"};
           myPort.Open();""

           string humidade = "", temperatura = "", heatIndex = "", lpgGas = "", monoCarbo = "", smoke = "", tempo = ""; 

           var macAddr = 
           (
               from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
               where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
               select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
           ).FirstOrDefault();
           Console.WriteLine("Mac adress do pc: {0}", macAddr);
           
           while (true)
           {
                   var dataRx = myPort.ReadLine(); 
                  

                   var underscore = dataRx.Split('_');
                   humidade = underscore[1];
                   temperatura = underscore[2];
                   heatIndex = underscore[3];
                   tempo = underscore[4];
                   lpgGas = underscore[5];
                   monoCarbo = underscore[6];
                   smoke = underscore[7];
                   
                 
                   Console.WriteLine(tempo);
                   Console.WriteLine(humidade);
                   Console.WriteLine(temperatura);
                   Console.WriteLine(heatIndex);
                   Console.WriteLine(lpgGas);
                   Console.WriteLine(monoCarbo);
                   Console.WriteLine(smoke);
                   Console.WriteLine("___________________");
     
           }

       }
 
   }
```

Comment: erro quer dizer que está a ler algum índice que não existe no array, pode por exemplo estar faltando a posição 5, 6,7, etc.. ponha isso no `try/catch` para capturar o erro e mostre o que tem na variável `underscore` e vais encontrar o problema

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro diz que você está tentando acessar um índice não existente no array.

Exemplo: temos um array de inteiros com 5 valores, ou seja, para acessar o primeiro elemento, começamos no índice 0, segundo elemento no índice 1 e assim sucessivamente.

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Considerando o array acima, se tentarmos acessar o índice 5, `array[5]`, iremos receber o erro `IndexOutOfRangeException`, porque o array só vai até o índice 4.

**Observação:** arrays em C# sempre começam no índice 0.

Voltando para o seu problema, você tem um array armazenado na variável de nome `underscore`  em que você espera que SEMPRE tenha 8 elementos nesse array (pois o último elemento que você tenta acessar é o índice 7 `underscore[7]`). Acontece que a forma que você obtém os valores desse array é por entrada manual de dados `Console.ReadLine()`, ou seja, tem grandes chances de erros, porque você está esperando dados em um formato específico `abc_123_456_def` (por exemplo) e pode ser que esses dados cheguem em um formato incorreto. O ideal seria que criasse uma validação para saber se os dados estão no formato que você deseja, e caso estejam corretos, você pode utilizá-los.

```
while (true)
{
    var dataRx = myPort.ReadLine();          

    var underscore = dataRx.Split('_');

    // Validação para não quebrar a aplicação e continuar o fluxo das próximas leituras de dados
    if (underscore.Length < 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados recebidos não estavam no formato correto.");
        continue;
    }

    humidade = underscore[1];
    temperatura = underscore[2];
    heatIndex = underscore[3];
    tempo = underscore[4];
    lpgGas = underscore[5];
    monoCarbo = underscore[6];
    smoke = underscore[7];
                          
    Console.WriteLine(tempo);
    Console.WriteLine(humidade);
    Console.WriteLine(temperatura);
    Console.WriteLine(heatIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(lpgGas);
    Console.WriteLine(monoCarbo);
    Console.WriteLine(smoke);
    Console.WriteLine("___________________"); 
}
```

Outro possível problema que eu imagino que possa ser, é que você começou a pegar os dados no índice 1, ou seja, talvez você não se lembrava que o array começa no índice 0. Se for esse o caso, é só subtrair 1 de cada índice.

```
while (true)
{
    var dataRx = myPort.ReadLine();          

    var underscore = dataRx.Split('_');

    // Validação para não quebrar a aplicação e continuar o fluxo das próximas leituras de dados
    if (underscore.Length < 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados recebidos não estavam no formato correto.");
        continue;
    }

    humidade = underscore[0];
    temperatura = underscore[1];
    heatIndex = underscore[2];
    tempo = underscore[3];
    lpgGas = underscore[4];
    monoCarbo = underscore[5];
    smoke = underscore[6];
                          
    Console.WriteLine(tempo);
    Console.WriteLine(humidade);
    Console.WriteLine(temperatura);
    Console.WriteLine(heatIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(lpgGas);
    Console.WriteLine(monoCarbo);
    Console.WriteLine(smoke);
    Console.WriteLine("___________________"); 
}
```

Eu continuaria com a validação, assim você evita futuros problemas caso os dados não cheguem no formato que você espera.

Espero ter ajudado.